# SQL Query Execution Plan Analyzer Tool

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I am using RDS Aurora PostgreSQL and I am new in PostgreSQL. I have been trying to analyze Execution Plans for queries in PostgreSQL.

I realized that manual audit on these plans take times, may need strict focus, and heavy effort as well. For example, this plan is complex for me.

```
QUERY PLAN
Hash Full Join  (cost=952458.62..1003967.53 rows=84905 width=114)
"  Hash Cond: (((s.id)::text = (dp.siteid)::text) AND ((s.organizationid)::text = (dp.organizationid)::text))"
"  ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=764029.81..811418.96 rows=84905 width=106)"
"        Hash Cond: (((s.id)::text = (fl.siteid)::text) AND ((s.organizationid)::text = (fl.organizationid)::text))"
"        ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=551181.40..594312.81 rows=84905 width=98)"
"              Hash Cond: (((s.id)::text = (l.siteid)::text) AND ((s.organizationid)::text = (l.organizationid)::text))"
"              ->  Hash Full Join  (cost=381576.41..424262.07 rows=84905 width=90)"
"                    Hash Cond: (((s.id)::text = (n.siteid)::text) AND ((s.organizationid)::text = (n.organizationid)::text))"
"                    ->  Merge Full Join  (cost=187046.05..226005.95 rows=84905 width=82)"
"                          Merge Cond: (((s.organizationid)::text = (device.organizationid)::text) AND ((s.id)::text = (device.siteid)::text))"
"                          ->  Index Only Scan using idx_site_org_site_heartbeat on site s  (cost=0.41..13536.51 rows=29107 width=74)"
"                          ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=187045.64..211050.29 rows=84905 width=82)"
"                                Group Key: device.organizationid, device.siteid"
"                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=187045.64..208927.67 rows=169810 width=82)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=186045.62..188327.36 rows=84905 width=82)"
"                                            Group Key: device.organizationid, device.siteid"
"                                            ->  Sort  (cost=186045.62..186403.79 rows=143269 width=74)"
"                                                  Sort Key: device.organizationid, device.siteid"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on device  (cost=0.00..167409.30 rows=143269 width=74)"
"                                                        Filter: ispartofsite"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=192521.93..192521.93 rows=70029 width=82)"
"                          ->  Subquery Scan on n  (cost=176213.83..192521.93 rows=70029 width=82)"
"                                ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=176213.83..191821.64 rows=70029 width=82)"
"                                      Group Key: device_1.organizationid, device_1.siteid"
"                                      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=176213.83..190280.22 rows=112150 width=82)"
"                                            Workers Planned: 2"
"                                            ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=175213.81..176335.31 rows=56075 width=82)"
"                                                  Group Key: device_1.organizationid, device_1.siteid"
"                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=175213.81..175353.99 rows=56075 width=74)"
"                                                        Sort Key: device_1.organizationid, device_1.siteid"
"                                                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on device device_1  (cost=0.00..168298.87 rows=56075 width=74)"
"                                                              Filter: (ispartofsite AND (networkstatus = 1))"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=169577.50..169577.50 rows=1833 width=82)"
"                    ->  Subquery Scan on l  (cost=169335.87..169577.50 rows=1833 width=82)"
"                          ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=169335.87..169559.17 rows=1833 width=82)"
"                                Group Key: device_2.organizationid, device_2.siteid"
"                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=169335.87..169529.27 rows=1542 width=82)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=168335.84..168351.26 rows=771 width=82)"
"                                            Group Key: device_2.organizationid, device_2.siteid"
"                                            ->  Sort  (cost=168335.84..168337.77 rows=771 width=74)"
"                                                  Sort Key: device_2.organizationid, device_2.siteid"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on device device_2  (cost=0.00..168298.87 rows=771 width=74)"
"                                                        Filter: (ispartofsite AND (dailynetworkloss >= 3))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=210420.92..210420.92 rows=84632 width=82)"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on fl  (cost=185738.00..210420.92 rows=84632 width=82)"
"                    ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=185738.00..209574.60 rows=84632 width=82)"
"                          Group Key: device_3.organizationid, device_3.siteid"
"                          ->  Gather Merge  (cost=185738.00..207458.80 rows=169264 width=82)"
"                                Workers Planned: 2"
"                                ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=184737.97..186921.51 rows=84632 width=82)"
"                                      Group Key: device_3.organizationid, device_3.siteid"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=184737.97..185072.28 rows=133722 width=74)"
"                                            Sort Key: device_3.organizationid, device_3.siteid"
"                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on device device_3  (cost=0.00..167409.30 rows=133722 width=74)"
"                                                  Filter: (ispartofsite AND (NOT firmwareinformation_islatest))"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=186637.96..186637.96 rows=62457 width=82)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on dp  (cost=173737.69..186637.96 rows=62457 width=82)"
"              ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=173737.69..186013.39 rows=62457 width=82)"
"                    Group Key: device_4.organizationid, device_4.siteid"
"                    ->  Gather Merge  (cost=173737.69..184731.43 rows=87652 width=82)"
"                          Workers Planned: 2"
"                          ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=172737.67..173614.19 rows=43826 width=82)"
"                                Group Key: device_4.organizationid, device_4.siteid"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=172737.67..172847.24 rows=43826 width=74)"
```

I am looking for a tool to guide me about execution plans. For instance, if there is any full-table-scan or if query does not use any index, the tool can highlight it etc.

Do you know any tool/linter to help analyzing execution plans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://explain.depesz.com/ is the one I always use. It has suggestions, and things like `SeqScan` are clickable and lead you to the related article.

Also, consider running `explain (verbose, analyze, buffers)` for better explains.

Answer (score 1):

In [Connecting to an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html#Aurora.Connecting.AuroraPostgreSQL), AWS recommends [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) as a GUI tool.

pgAdmin lets you generate the *Explain* or *Explain Analyze* plan of a query by clicking the *Explain* or *Explain Analyze* button in the toolbar. This opens the [Explain Panel](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.12/query_tool.html#explain-panel), which shows the explain plan as a graph and as a table, as well as statistics for the plan and for the table.

You can also use [Performance Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.html) from the AWS console to monitor database load, identify expensive queries and generate their execution plans. This is useful for discovering and diagnosing performance issues in production or load tests.